# When I use sprintf to output a string of size 3 and a character to a string of size 5, I get a segmentation fault (core dump)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I changed the pointer to an array, or allocate more memory, but to no avail.

I look other issues about it, but still can't solve me questions.

Below is the code I wrote(use 9.3.0 gcc in ubuntu):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* str1 = malloc(5);
    char* str2 = "666";
    sprintf("%s%c", str1, str2, '6');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the order of the arguments should be like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* str1 =(char*) malloc(5);
    char* str2 = "666";
    sprintf(str1,"%s%c",str2,'6');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the order of the parameters to sprintf. The format string is the second and the target buffer is the first.

Comment: oh my god! I actually made such a stupid question! It caused me to waste an entire afternoon. . .